# Jenkins-Rest - Connect to remote jenkins client

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

I have a scenario where I want to trigger Jenkins Build with parameters remotely.

I am using following jar in my java code to connect to Jenkins:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.cdancy</groupId>
   <artifactId>jenkins-rest</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.25</version>
   <classifier>all</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Following is the code snippet I use to check Jenkins version.

```
JenkinsClient client = JenkinsClient.builder()
// Note - I tried endpoint as https://(//my IP goes here):(//my port goes here) without /jenkins suffix. It didnt work also
.endPoint("https://(//my IP goes here):(//my port goes here)/jenkins").
credentials("username:password").build();

SystemInfo systemInfo = client.api().systemApi().systemInfo();
System.out.println(systemInfo.jenkinsVersion());
```

I get the following error:

```
SystemInfo{errors=[Error{context=null, message=Unexpected exception being thrown: error=Error{context=null, message=PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target connecting to GET host name goes here/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat%28//crumbRequestField,%22%3A%22,//crumb%29 HTTP/1.1, exceptionName=com.cdancy.jenkins.rest.shaded.org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException} connecting to HEAD HTTP/1.1, exceptionName=com.cdancy.jenkins.rest.shaded.org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException}]
```

How do I set the SSLContext/certificate with the Jenkins client?

Or should I use any other dependency to connect to Jenkins and build a job with parameters?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To increase the Jenkins API security Cloudbees uses crumb read more on this here
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained

Instead of using password try to use an API Token.
Open User settings, top right corner --> Configure --> Add new Token
Then use the token instead of the password in your java code